# Как отделять ответы пользователя от других команд?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, telegram-bot

Подскажите, как сделать в телеграмм боте заполнение брифа. Собственно есть бот. Выводит услуги компании. Необходимо сделать отдельную кнопку "Заполнить бриф". После нажатия задается вопрос, пользователь пишет ответ. И так далее.

Не пойму, как сделать. То есть понятно:

- Что вопросы в БД.
- Что проверять.
- Есть ответ на запрос или нет.

Не понятно, как отделять ответы пользователя от других команд.
Возможно, вписывать в поле ввода свою команду, после которой пользователь должен ввести ответ (например "/brif Евгений"). Потом разбирать регуляркой.

Как это возможно реализовать?

Вообще возможно из скрипта вписывать в поле ввода?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю сделать историю действий пользователя и отталкиваться от этого уже.
Например пользовать нажал кнопку «Заполнить бриф».
И в БД или где-то вы храните данные, фиксировать, что данный пользовать нажал кнопку «Заполнить бриф» и принимать сообщения только в этом случае для заполнения брифа.

Примерно такая таблица, а так зависит от случая, надеюсь идея решения проблемы была полезной:

```
CREATE TABLE history(
  id INT,
  user_id INT,
  command VARCHAR,
  PRIMARY KEY ( id)
);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я собственно к этому и пришел. Решил посоветоваться. может есть какие то реализации. И кто то натолкнет на другие варианты.

Comment: @ЕвгенийМалеев Сам думал достаточно и пока только такой вариант вижу)